# Use Taps in JRuby

Tags: ruby, jruby, taps

I am trying to running [Taps](https://github.com/ricardochimal/taps) in JRuby, but it always fail. It seems there's something wrong with the SQLite3:

```
taps server sqlite:///my-db.sqlite3 user passwd

/usr/bin/java: symbol lookup error: ~/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7.2/gems/sqlite3-1.3.6/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.so: undefined symbol: rb_check_safe_obj
```

Is there any body get stuck in this like me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

After hours of searching and looking through the code of Taps, I found the answer myself :D.
The problem is native SQLite in JRuby is a madness, we must use JDBC instead.

```
export TAPS_DATABASE_URL="jdbc:sqlite:///tmp/taps.db.2012-08-07"
taps server jdbc:sqlite:///my-db.sqlite3 user passwd
```

The first command is to prevent Taps from creating it internal DB with native sqlite connection. Taps will use ENV['TAPS_DATABASE_URL'].
In the second command, we must add a prefix 'jdbc:' to instruct Taps (actually Taps use [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/files/doc/opening_databases_rdoc.html)) connect to DB with JDBC adapter.